# Android : Issue using PagerSlidingTabStrip when I rotate the device the selected nav tab is shifted on the right

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using the library PagerSlidingTabStrip for my navigation tabs with a view pager. I follow this sample from the github page of the library :[PagerSlidingTabStrip sample](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/MainActivity.java).

It works well, when I slide the view it works but there is an issue that I don't how fixe: When I rotate the device , the nav tab selected is shifted on the right but my view on the view pager is the good. If I slide little bit the view, then the nav tab selected is updating. Moreover if I rotate again my device, then the good nav tab selected is updating also.

If someone has already fix this issue, I would like some help.

Thx,

**EDIT :** In fact it is an issue from the library because I clone the sample from github and run it in my nexus 5 and I have the same issue...

Comment: On what device are you testing this? On my Nexus 4 it behaves as expected.

Comment: Have you solved this isse? Same for me...